# The set of limit points of the sequence $1,\frac12,\frac14,\frac34,\frac18,\frac38,\frac58,\frac78,\frac1{16},\frac3{16},\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across the following problem that says:

> The set of limit points of the sequence $1,\dfrac12,\dfrac14,\dfrac34,\dfrac18,\dfrac38,\dfrac58,\dfrac78,\dfrac1{16},\dfrac3{16},\dfrac5{16},\dfrac7{16},\dfrac9{16},\ldots$ is which of the following?
>   (a) $[0,1]$
>   (b) $(0,1]$
>   (c) the set of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$
>   (d) the set of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and of the form $m/2^n$ where $m$ and $n$
>   are integers.

Please help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So, what do you know about limit points of sequences? Can you prove, for example, that $0$ is in the set? That will rule out (b), and maybe help you see how to do the problem.

Comment: It says to choose the best option.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks a lot sir for your feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The given sequence is a listing of all the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ for some integers $m>0$ and $n\geq 0$. The set of rational numbers of this form turns out to be dense in $[0,1]$, so if by "limit points" you mean "points having infinitely many terms of the sequence in every neighborhood around them", then the answer is $[0,1]$.

Comment: It is true that set of all rational points is dense in $[0,1]$. But the set mentioned is not set of all rational numbers but only rational numbers of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$. I think, we need more justification to conclude.

Comment: You're correct that justification is needed. It certainly isn't true that all subsets of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ are dense in $[0,1],$ but that isn't what I'm claiming. I will adjust my phrasing to avoid this confusion (as well as fixing a typo I just found).

Answer (score 8):

Let $x\in[0,1]$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon$. Then there is a positive integer $m$ such that $x\neq\frac{m}{2^n}\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap[0,1]$. But $\frac{m}{2^n}$ is an element of the given sequence. Hence the set of limit points is $[0,1]$.

Comment: Saw the anger in the chatroom, so +1.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the first 8 terms (reordered): $$\frac{1}{8}, \frac{2}{8}, \frac{3}{8}, \frac{4}{8}, \frac{5}{8}, \frac{6}{8}, \frac{7}{8}, \frac{8}{8}$$

This pattern continues as the denominator grows throughout the sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryce for your feedback.