# Find all limit points of the sequence $\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{3}; \frac{2}{3}; \frac{1}{4}; \frac{2}{4}; \frac{3}{4}; \frac{1}{5}; \frac{2}{5}; \dotso$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analysis, real-numbers

I know that the answer is all real numbers on $[0, 1]$, but I can’t pick out the subsequences.
Please help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268195/the-set-of-limit-points-of-the-sequence-1-frac12-frac14-frac34-frac18-frac?rq=1).

Comment: Not exactly, but certainly all real numbers from $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, there is a different sequence and not entirely obvious solution.

Comment: Therefore I said "compare". I am sure it helps.

Comment: Intuitively: the fractions are all equidistant subdivisions of $[0,1]$ with an increasing number of parts. Hence any real in $(0,1)$ will be bracketed by pairs of terms as close as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x\in(0,1)$ and $n\geq2$, take $a_n=\frac{\lfloor xn\rfloor}{n}$ if $xn>1$ and $a_n=\frac1n$ otherwise (since $\frac0n$ is not the sequence).    Since the denominators are strictly increasing in this sequence, it is a subsequence of the given sequence.  And since $|x-a_n|<\frac1n$ for all $n\geq2$, the sequence converges to $x$.

And $(\frac 1n\mid n\geq 2)$ and $(\frac{n-1}n\mid n\geq 2)$ converge to $0$ and $1$ respectively.  (Thanks to Peter Foreman for pointing that out.)

(For all of these families, assign $a_1$ and $a_0$ to be whatever you like if not being a proper sequence feels important to you.)

Comment: It’s not very clear, do you have parentheses or a module in the fraction numerator?

Comment: @WOODKEEPER It is the floor function (i.e. the function where you always round down to the nearest integer).

Comment: @PeterForeman Good catch.  Those subsequences are added now.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Note that you need to start at $n = \lceil 1/x\rceil$, or else $\lfloor xn\rfloor/n = 0$, which isn't an element of the original sequence.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Argh, strike 2 against me for oversimplifying the solution.  I think I've corrected that now!